# Python Selenium webdriver always errors instead of starting either Chrome, Firefox, Edge

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to run example python code which includes the webdriver:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

I get the following error, which also includes an html dump complaining about trying to access a restricted website.  All of this seems to be output from webdriver.Chrome:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\a0233720\Python projects\webdriver test.py", line 4, in 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in **init**
> super().**init**(
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in **init**
> super().**init**(
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 209, in check_response
> raise exception_class(value)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

Tried different arguments to webdriver, tried to use the 3 different browsers, firefox, chrome, edge, tried the requests.get() approach, tried using proxy. Got same or worse results. Spent many weeks on this.  I was hoping to see the browser pop up, or htlm of google.com

Comment: Change this line, driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe'). Backslashes have to be either specified by using \\ or r string. Like webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe') or webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe')